# How Can I execute external program with arguments in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I want to launch external Program with Arguments(one of the argument is to load the Config file to that external program) after I click the button of javafx app(the btn event not included in the code) but I wonder why it keeps giving me errors!

My IDE is InjellJ IDEA Community edition

I know this question is the duplicate but among all the examples given here in this platform have been tried with no sucess however my code contains config file as part of the argumets

Here is the code

```
private String appDomain = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
private String exepath = appDomain+"\\src\\bin\\exeResources\\MyExe.exe";
private String exeargs = appDomain+"\\src\\bin\\exeResources\\MyExe.ppx silent-load";

try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        r.exec(exepath +" "+exeargs);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when I remove the "**exeargs**" I get the error 
CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Making it difficult for me to know if "**exeargs**" can work with the above snippet.

Your help will be appreciated

EDIT

The exefile and execonfig I have to load is located in one of the package in my project `**bin.exeResource**`
Printing the paths and args by

```
System.out.println(exepath+" "+exeargs);
```

Gives me

```
C:\Users\{MyUser}\OneDrive\IntelliJ IDEA Projects\MyProject Package\src\bin\exeResources\MyExe.exe ...\src\bin\exeResources\MyExe.ppx silent-load
```

with an Error

```
CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Have you printed out the result of `exepath`? Does it include any spaces? Are you sure that the executable is, in fact, in that path? It seems that you are looking for a relative directory, and that may fail if your current directory is not the one above the `src` directory.

Comment: The .exe file is Intact sir!
and I edited the question and added the output when I try to print the arguments and the error I get!
Note that the .exe file is located in the package bin\exeResources

Comment: Ah, so there is a space in the path. "IntelliJ IDEA Projects" - that contains spaces. So it thinks the command is `C:\Users\{MyUser}\OneDrive\IntelliJ` and fails. I'm going to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `exec` method specifically overloaded for your purposes. It takes as an argument String array which holds the command and the arguments for the command. That seems to be exactly what you need. Please look at the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[]))

Comment: Thank you very much this Solved my problem!

Comment: Great, I am happy to help, why don't you up-vote the answer and mark it as the one that resolved the problem?

Comment: I upvoted you but stackoverflow gives me a notification that if my reputation is less than 15 the Uptvote is not shown to the public

Comment: OK, thanks and good luck

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing about the exe arguments. Try this one:

```
private String appDomain = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
private String exepath = appDomain + "\\src\\bin\\exeResources\\MyExe.exe";
private String exeargs = "silent-load";

try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        r.exec(exepath + " " + exeargs);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Note that with this arguments you have omitted that Option of Loading the Profile name or "exe config" check the "exeargs" again!

**...\\MyExe.ppx silent-load**